# Replace bbcode to HTML in PHP

Tags: html, replace, bbcode

For several weeks I learn a lot from this site.

Now I search for hours for a tip but can not find it and I decided to post a question.

I want an image from bbcode filter and a style as I add, but I do not know how to do this.

Who can tell me how can in chage this:

```
[attach=news-ZmAk6khfk0.jpg align=left title=title width=500 height=500 rel=rel]<br />
De formatie van Rutten creëerde in het eerste bedrijf geen uitgespeelde kansen. Vanuit de tweede lijn vielen een paar schoten te noteren. Dries Mertens en Tim Matavz hadden het vizier niet op scherp staan.
```

To this:

```
<img src=news-ZmAk6khfk0.jpg align=left title=title width=500 height=500 border=0 class=footblocks/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the PEAR package [BBCode Parser 2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser2). It's an excellent tool that will save you hours.

**Edit:** PECL also has one similar to the PEAR version: [BBCode Parser](http://pecl.php.net/package/bbcode)

Comment: I'm new and I have no idea what to do :(
Can you give me some examples how I can do?

Comment: @faruknl Most webhosting providers give you a PECL or PEAR installer to use and install new packages. If you're using PHP locally, simply download the package and install it yourself. They provide a good amount of documentation on the site.